# Why is app shutting down and catch-clause doesn´t catch error?

Tags: java, android

I have two fields that i want to calculate. The program works fine if i put in numbers in both fields, but if i have one empty and presses my "buttonSubtract" (calc-button) it just shuts down with "application closed...". Why doesn´t the catch-clause catch the exception?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonSubtract = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonsubtract);
    editTextNumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textnumber1);
    editTextNumber2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textnumber2);
    textSum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSum);

    try
    buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (editTextNumber1.getText().toString() == ""
                        || editTextNumber2.getText().toString() == "")
                {
                    textSum.setText("Put numbers in both fields");

                } else
                {
                    int sum = Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber1.getText()
                            .toString())
                            - Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber2.getText()
                                    .toString());
                    textSum.setText("sum: " + sum);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        textSum.setText("Put numbers in both fields");
    }
```

Comment: Check logcat for more information on exceptions and add them to your question.

Comment: maybe a `NullPointerException`? Have a stacktrace or logcat?

Comment: @DaveG, i will sure look into that, thanks.

Comment: Sorry wasn't reading the code properly accepted answer below +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't catch exceptions that are thrown in an inner class from the outside. Move the `try` / `catch` block to the place where the `NumberFormatException` happens.

```
    buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String number1 = editTextNumber1.getText().toString().trim();
            String number2 = editTextNumber2.getText().toString().trim();
            if (!number1.isEmpty() && !number2.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    int sum = Integer.parseInt(number1)
                            + Integer.parseInt(number2);
                    textSum.setText("sum: " + sum);
                    return;

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    // nothing to do
                }
            }
            textSum.setText("Put numbers in both fields");
        }
    });
```

The reason is simple: the code executed inside `onClick` is not called by you. It is called by the system once a click happens. Exceptions are only propagated to the caller.

It's simpler to see if you re-arrange the code a bit. Your code was equivalent to

```
OnClickListener someListener = getListener(); // this creates your implementation.
try {
    buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(someListener);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Always Compare String with .equals() method, `==` operator will check if two reference variables point/refer to the same Object:

```
if (editTextNumber1.getText().toString() == "" || editTextNumber2.getText().toString() == "")
```

should be
    if(editTextNumber1.getText().toString().equals("")||editTextNumber2.getText().toString().equals(""))

Or even better you can use [**String.isEmpty()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty%28%29) to check if the string is empty.

Now, Regarding the actual problem:

Move your try/catch around the code which throw NumberFormatException for your catch to catch the exception.

```
   try {    
       int sum = Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber1.getText().toString())
                            - Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber2.getText().toString());
       textSum.setText("sum: " + sum);
   }
   catch(numberFormatException ex) {
       //do the stuff
     }
```

Comment: Although this is correct, that comparison wouldn´t throw an exception, which is the problem being encountered. It is just a comparison between two pointers that will always return false.

Answer (score 1):

You only have a catch block for a NumberFormatException. Many other exceptions could be thrown before the block, or inside it. For instance, if any of the findViewById() methods you call at the beginning returns a null, any call to methods of that variable would throw a NullPointerException.

Check the logCat to see what exception is being thrown.

Comment: I have a exception block outside that should catch everything.. by the way, whats the logCat?

Comment: No, you don´t. The try/catch block will only catch an exception thrown by the setOnClickListener() method, not by the method inside the OnClickListener class itself. The methods of that class will be executed later, and the try/catch block should be inside the OnClick() method, as zapl has answered.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html. The Eclipse ADT plugin includes a tab for viewing the logcat of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions thrown in your OnClickListener implementation will bot be caught by your try..catch statement because you are just creating it and setting as a listener, but not executing. It will be executed in other thread later, remove that and put your try..catch statement inside the onclick method.

Also you forgot a "{" after try, and you can't compare Strings with `==`, it will compare if the variables has the same objects instead if they are equals. Use the `equals(Object o)` method instead, and to check if it's empty it's better to trim the string and use the `isEmpty()` method `"sample".trim().isEmpty()`

```
buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            try
            {
                if (editTextNumber1.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
                        || editTextNumber2.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty())
                {
                    textSum.setText("Put numbers in both fields");

                } else
                {
                    int sum = Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber1.getText()
                            .toString())
                            - Integer.parseInt(editTextNumber2.getText()
                                    .toString());
                    textSum.setText("sum: " + sum);
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException e)
            {
                textSum.setText("Put numbers in both fields");
            }
        }
    });
```